# How to have VBA change the pivot data fields to xlsum

Tags: vba, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot where in the data fields are about 178 fields. 
I want them all to use the xlsum function. Doing this manually takes a lot of time so I looked for a way to do this by VBA.
First, I used the macro recorder and changed 2 or 3 fields to see what the code looks like.

Then, I tried to write a code which could do the same for all the used data fields.

However, I have not succeeded in this. I used google to find similar questions and tried to use the code from there. I still did not succeed.

Hopefully, someone can help me getting this to work.
I found codes which refer directly to a hard named data field. But that is not what I need.

What I have now is:

```
Sub PivotTableSummaryFunctions1b()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Blad4").PivotTables("Draaitabel")

For Each PvtTbl.DataPivotField In PvtTbl.DataFields
.Function = xlsum

Next

End With

End Sub
```

What should I change to have the code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this code now, which works perfectly fine for me now:

```
Sub AddAllFieldsValues()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iColEnd As Long

Set pt = Worksheets("pivot_long_term").PivotTables("Draaitabel1")

With pt
.ManualUpdate = True
    .DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
    iCol = 5
   iColEnd = .PivotFields.Count

    For iCol = 5 To 32
        With .PivotFields(iCol)
          If .Orientation = 0 Then
              .Orientation = xlDataField
          End If
        End With
    Next iCol

.ManualUpdate = False
Worksheets("pivot_long_term").PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotCache.refresh

.ManualUpdate = True

For Each pf In .DataFields
With pf
.Function = xlSum
.Caption = "." & .SourceName
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With
Next pf
.ManualUpdate = False
End With

pt.PivotCache.refresh

End Sub
Sub AsSum()
Dim pf As PivotField
With Worksheets("pivot_long_term").PivotTables("Draaitabel1")
.ManualUpdate = True
For Each pf In .DataFields
With pf
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With
Next pf
.ManualUpdate = False
End With

Worksheets("pivot_long_term").PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotCache.refresh


End Sub
Sub Printshee
```

and 1 other option (code I use for another format, but which is about the same):

```
Sub AsSum()
Dim pf As PivotField
With Worksheets("Blad4").PivotTables("Draaitabel1")
.ManualUpdate = True
For Each pf In .DataFields
With pf
.Function = xlsum
.Caption = "." & .SourceName
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With
Next pf
.ManualUpdate = False
End With

Worksheets("Blad4").PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
Sub AddAllFieldsValues()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iColEnd As Long

Set pt = Worksheets("blad4").PivotTables("Draaitabel1")

With pt
.ManualUpdate = True
    .DataPivotField.Orientation = xlHidden
    iCol = 4
   iColEnd = .PivotFields.Count

    For iCol = 4 To iColEnd
        With .PivotFields(iCol)
          If .Orientation = 0 Then
              .Orientation = xlDataField
          End If
        End With
    Next iCol
.ManualUpdate = False
Worksheets("blad4").PivotTables("Draaitabel1").PivotCache.Refresh
End With

End Sub
```